# is possible to send printing with mach3?

Tags: printer-building, cnc

I was wondering if is possible to send printing using the software MACH3 for CNC since this software can handle up to 3 axes: X,Y,Z,A,B and C.
Of course the CNC needs an extra control for temperature which I already have it; My CNC handle a Z axis with 150mm height, so I could print higher parts than normal CNC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, few years ago I could set the software Mach3 for printing doing the next:

1. **Set a profile for 3D printing** for the faster movements that your CNC can support; for example some CNC uses standard threads, others ACME threads and other GT2 belts like the 3D printers. If we try to use a feed rate too high the motors will shake. For this profile is not needed the torque for machining or routing, so we will sacrifice force to gain speed.
2. **Create the proper gcode**. Mostly Gcode maker generate the code to send pulses to Extruder E but Mach3 takes as invalid E instructions, so the extruder will never move. To avoid this there are 2 modes:

**a)** Find and replace all E instruction with A to enable Motor A or

**b)** Create the Gcode with an interpreter to output A instead E
    like Slicer 0.71 as you can see in the image below. I haven't tried with other software

[image]

3.**For controlling the extruder temperature** is possible with any other controller like REX-C100/C400 any PIC or Arduino. The accuracy will depend on your design.